# Is there a way simple Encrypt/Decrypt in MAUI .Net8?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, maui

I looked it up, googled it, and tried a few methods.
But it seems these methods mostly work for Windows C# application and will fail when I call it on Android for example:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
public string Encrypt(string plainText, string? password = null)
{
    var data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(plainText);
    var pwd = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) ? Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password) : Array.Empty<byte>();
    var cipher = ProtectedData.Protect(data, pwd, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipher);
}

public string Decrypt(string cipherText, string? password = null)
{
    var cipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    var pwd = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) ? Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password) : Array.Empty<byte>();
    var data = ProtectedData.Unprotect(cipher, pwd, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
    return Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
}
```

What I need is something simple just to Encrypt/Decrypt a string like Password. Or something safe to store strings for Android/Windows/IOS.

I have read through the SecureStorage documentation but it seems quite complicated compared to just implementing the 2 Encrypt/Decrypt Functions that I often use on NetFramework Windows Form. Then I just call the Function and use it.

Comment: Have you looked at Secure Storage? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android

Comment: I've not tried on Android, but `System.Security.Encryption` contains managed implementations of various codecs that should work on all platforms (except `browser`). Have you tried `Aes.Create()` (for symmetric encryption) or `RSA.Create()` (for asymmetric)?

Comment: A password should not be encrypted, but hashed. Compare hashed newvalue to stored hash to determine equality, not decrypt and compare plaintext versions.

Comment: "will fail when I call it on Android " - this is not a helpful description of the problem.  What specifically fails?  What is the error or exception?

Comment: so secure storage is the place to store something securely. consider it like a vault. to encrypt a decrypt you would need an algorithm, consider it like instructions on how to transform something to look like something else, using some ingredients. after it is transformed you can share it and only the people with the (or some) ingredients can transform it back. you would need a safe place to store those ingredients, like in a vault (secure storage).

Comment: so protected data is a way to let .net encrypt something for you. like connection strings in a config file. it uses one of the algorithms. you can also manually use .net built in functions for different algorithms, without you having to write the algorithm. that is what System.Security.Cryptography is about, like RSA, ECD, and more. for cross platform, .net5+ can be used with almost all the algorithms. but not ProtectedData. ProtectedData is only for windows. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Comment: so what you need is one of the manual encryption classes that already have the algorithm coded for you. this page has example code and is for the AES algorithm: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-8.0

Comment: the encryption classes that are not CNG are made cross platform, but may not work in ALL platforms. CNG are only for windows. after you choose the algorithm you want, you can store the secret keys in SecureStorage, which is also cross platform. here is what algorithms work in what platforms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography

Comment: 1 last thing, as someone else pointed out, you dont want to encrypt passwords. you want to hash them. the difference is that a hash cannot be decrypted. and you want to use a hash that is higher than MD5, since MD5 and below are not secure anymore.